# refactoring d3 js code from v5.16 to v6.6.2, d3.event breaking change

Tags: javascript, d3.js, migration

New to d3 and fixing an error. I am working with a js file using the d3 library. The following line of code does not error out in v5.16:

```
    function br(d) {
        let s = d3.event.selection || xScaleSelector.range()
        let extent = s.map(xScaleSelector.invert, xScaleSelector);
        let window = data.filter(d => d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1])
        update(window)
    }
```

However, when migrating to v6.6.2 and above, I get an error. The error I am getting is on line: `let s = d3.event.selection || xScaleSelector.range()` with the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'selection')`.

The origin of the error, according to https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v6.0.0, v6.0.0 has removed the `d3.event`. (d3.event is undefined in v6). Can someone help suggest what changes I can make to fix this error when migrating to >= v6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
function br(d) {
    let s = d.selection || xScaleSelector.range()
    let extent = s.map(xScaleSelector.invert, xScaleSelector);
    let window = data.filter(d => d.date >= extent[0] && d.date <= extent[1])
    update(window)
}
```

Per the migration guide [here](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide)